# Links are displayed as HTML/URL (= not clickable)

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

In [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/6054/1859) the author used the following syntax to link to external pages:

> ```
> Most commonly are the rules from [Duden][1] or from ["Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung"][2]  quoted.
>
>   [1]: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln
>   [2]: http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf
> ```

The links are *displayed* as HTML/URL instead of being clickable.

> ```
> Most commonly are the rules from http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln"&gt;Duden or from http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf"&gt;"Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung"  quoted.
> ```

However, when editing this answer, it's correctly displayed in the preview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Markdown links and images are producing incorrect HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165096/markdown-links-and-images-are-producing-incorrect-html) on Meta Stack Overflow. This bug was fixed; I have made a no-op edit to the answer to force re-rendering it correctly.